# Why does first yum update on CentOS 7 ask to accept keys

Tags: centos, security, yum

I ran `yum update` on a newly built machine.

- Why does it ask to accept keys?
- Is it safe to accept the keys?

```
base/7/x86_64/signature                                                                                             |  811 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

Note, I did change the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` added base URL to a near by public (ISP) repo.

I also change the `/etc/yum.conf` and added/modified the following:

```
repo_gpgcheck=1
payload_gpgcheck=1
plugins=0
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason `yum` ask is because you do not have installed this key on your machine. This will happen on every new machine. You can switch it off by changing:

```
repo_gpgcheck=0
```

You can trust those keys if the fingerprint match with one of those [here](https://www.centos.org/keys/)

Comment: Thanks.  Since posting the question I have already checked them and they match.  I was surprised that it doesn't come installed already.  In other words why doesn't in come with the install media (I did use the minimal version).  I am used to other distros where AFAIK is key is installed at install time.

Comment: @NewCentOSuser, from security point of view its wise to do not put them together. If someone alter some package and sign it with own key and add this key you will not be able to recognize it and do not install it

Comment: Makes sense now that you have explained it.  It seems the Centos approach seems like a better one as you are force to accept it and it displays the fingerprint.    I suppose you can tamper with the display code too, but at least it makes you think about it.

Comment: I ran into it while executing `yum install vim` on a newly created AWS EC2 instance ([official CentOS AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW)). Before that, I launched a CentOS VM (`VirtualBox`) a number of times, where I installed CentOS manually. And I don't remember `yum` asking me such questions. Is that really expected?

Comment: @x-yuri, probably in AWS the keys are already installed in to the AMI

Comment: It seems the other way around, the official CentOS AMI comes with no keys imported. But when you install the OS (e.g. inside a VirtualBox VM), they get imported automatically. Although I'm not sure, I did the latter a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against disabling the signature checks. What's happening here is manifold:

Repo configurations (in "/etc/yum.repos.d") define the URL of a GPG public key with which the repo and packages are signed. For package installation, the key must be imported into the RPM system's key store.

> Why does it ask to accept keys?

Because the key has not been imported into the RPM key store yet. I am uncertain when and why that is the case for default keys such as the official CentOS Signing Key, but it appears to happen.

> Is it safe to accept the keys?

In your case, the key URL has a `file://` scheme with a file in "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg". Since that directory is owned by root and the file must have been installed there somehow, I'd say it's pretty safe. This assessment might be different for other URLs. Of course, fingerprint checks can provide additional security.

In addition to the package signing with keys managed by the RPM system, the `repo_gpgcheck` setting controls whether [signatures on repository metadata](https://blog.centos.org/2018/07/improving-centos-package-delivery-security-with-signed-repository-metadata/) are checked as well. For that, keys must be imported into yet another key store located at "/var/lib/yum/*/gpgdir" (legacy) or "/var/cache/dnf/*/pubring" (RHEL/CentOS 8). When the keys have not yet been added to these stores, you may be also be asked to import them – and the prompt for that look just like the one for the RPM key store.